# Alexa Skill Linking with RoR Backend fails in Alexa App because of session lost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, alexa-skills-kit, doorkeeper

I developed an Alexa Skill which connects to a Ruby on Rails Backend to push and pull some data. 
The Backend is also used for the user management and authentication.
I'm using doorkeeper gem and devise gem for this purpose. 
For Oauth authorization I'm using Auth Code Grant.

When I'm using the browser version of Alexa, everything is working fine. First time user tries to connect, he will be redirect to the login page and after login page is redirected back to Alexa app with corresponding tokens.

BUT when I use the Alexa app on iOS (like most users will do), no session is created when starting the connection process. And in this way it's not possible to share the data between the redirects. 
Every time I'm redirecting, for example to the login page, the session is gone. So I could try to work with a lot of url parameters but I'm still wondering why it's not working in the app while working in the browser...

Does that make sense to anyone?

I'm glad for any help or idea. Thanks in advance guys.

Best,
Chris